# Create a similar homepage layout to moviepilot.com with two scrolling content areas?

Tags: jquery, css, layout, html, graphic

How can i create a similar layout to http://moviepilot.com/. What i am interested in the most is how they created the two scrolling content areas. Would i be able to develop this in jquery? Or is there a simpler way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/9rVzF/3/

Here is how they did it.

The left is "position: fixed;" to the screen. So when you "scroll the page" the right side scrolls, with the left part still not looking scrolled.

When you scroll in the left, the page stays the same, just that div is scrolled in, leaving then right part not looking scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `overflow:auto;`

And also you should use `position` property also.
Background image is fixed , that's why right side scrolling ,
Any way you can do all these things only using css.

try this link  [overflow](http://www.1keydata.com/css-tutorial/overflow.php)

[position property](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

They are created only one scrolling area, other is scrolling by default :) How to create scrolling area? Magic is in `overflow: auto`. Give some container fixed position, and `overflow: auto;` and there you go. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d4EQB/)